# Drawing 800+ circles in a space-themed shoorter game

Tags: java, performance, game, graphics

I am making a space-themed shooter game, and I need to render many "lasers" at the same time. I am using the library Slick2D, a wrapper around `lwjgl`. Unfortunately, when there are a lot of these "lasers" on the screen at one time, the game drops from its usual 60 FPS to around 30 or even 20.

Things I've noticed:

- Not calling `drawSelf` = no lag
- Not calling `.fill` = no lag
- As is = lag as stated in title

```
public void drawSelf(Graphics g){
    int[] pos = tr.toSlick(blast.getPosition());
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    Circle circle = new Circle(pos[0], pos[1], tr.xscale/2);
    g.fill(circle);
}

public int[] toSlick(float x, float y){
    int [] output = new int[2];
    output[0] = (int)(x*xscale+width/2);
    output[1] = (int)(-1*y*yscale+height/2);
    return output;
}
```

`tr` is the coordinate transformer object (I'm using `jbox2d` physics, but that's not impacting anything), and blast is the "Body".

Can I have some suggestions on making this code faster or am I stuck because of Slick's internals?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.fill()` call?

Comment: @200_success hmm, I have not tried that. I will update my question when I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at documentation, I found another method that is faster at drawing many circles.

I replaced last 2 lines in `drawSelf` with:

```
g.fillOval(pos[0],pos[1],tr.xscale,tr.yscale);
```

and I got a **lot** less lag. Turns out it did have to do with internals.